# SQLException With Character from Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have data in a table:

```
CodeID    ColOne          ColTwo
---------------------------------------
1         DATAONE         DATAONE
2         DATATWO-Test    DATA-TEST1
```

Here is my code:

```
public static Codes [] Fetch(IDataProxy proxy, string whereClause, params FetchParameter [] parameters)
{
    List<Codes> list = new List<Codes>();
    using(IDbCommand cmd = proxy.Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [CodeID],[ColOne],[ColTwo] FROM [Codes]";
        using(IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            while(reader.Read()) {
                list.Add(new Codes(reader));
            }
        }
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

When I retrive the second result, I get an error message on Line 7 at "cmd.ExecuteReader()". The error message is as follows:

`Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'DATATWO'. Incorrect syntax near 'DATATWO'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for all your help!

**Edit**:

Here is Codes:

```
internal Codes(IDataReader reader)
{
   this.CodeID = reader.GetInt32(0);
   this.ColOne = reader.GetString(1);
   this.ColTwo = reader.GetString(2);
   this.DataState = System.Data.DataRowState.Unchanged;
}
```

Comment: Post Codes class definition

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: @Steve: Sounds, like this is Excel file

Comment: Weird, the ExecuteReader should be executed just one time, not two as you say. And if the error is at the ExecuteReader line I can't see how this error could be raised by this code.

Comment: May be Error is here `this.ColOne = reader.GetString(1);` ??

Comment: Or this is not the full code. Look at the parameters passed to the method. Where are they used?

Comment: The parameters are null in this case, they're not used.

Comment: The error lies in the "cmd.ExecuteReader()" when it reads "DATATWO-Test" from the table.

Comment: Go to DB and change that record to something else and test

Comment: I overlooked something, in my example, I didn't include my "where" clause and the select statement was: `where ColOne = 'DATATWO-Test`. I didn't have the closing ' after the value.

Comment: You should select your own answer as answer and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked something, in my example, I didn't include my "where" clause and the select statement was: `where ColOne = 'DATATWO-Test`. I didn't have the closing ' after the value.